# Why does using Convert.ToString not make this work, but new string does?

Tags: c#, string, new-operator

I am trying to write a program that takes in a string and reverses it, and after looking online I came up upon this solution,

```
password = new string(password.ToCharArray().Reverse<char>().ToArray());
```

My question is, why does 'new string' return the correct answer, but 'Convert.ToString' doesn't, I know there is a difference between them and I'm trying to learn that difference so I can improve as a programmer.

Comment: Did you try logging (or inspecting with a debugger) the result of `Convert.ToString`?

Comment: Convert.ToString acepts a char as input but no a char _Array_ https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=net-6.0

Comment: Why do you want to convert a string to a string?  Conversions can change the data?

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is returning a char array (char[]):

```
password.ToCharArray().Reverse<char>().ToArray()
```

In the String documentation :

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0#constructors

You can see "String(Char[])" meaning the String object can take a char array as a parameter

If you look at the MSDN Documentation of Convert.ToString : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=net-6.0

You can see that the method ToString of Convert does not accept a char array as a possible parameter.

That's why new string works and not Convert.ToString().